# Дубликаты в списке

Tags: python, list, список

```
a = []
row = []
for b in range(1,5):
    a.append(b)
    date.append(a)
    print("попытка", b, ":", date, end="\n")
    row.clear()
    a.clear()
```

При добавлении списка (после он очищается и добавляются новые данные) в список данные почему-то дублируются:

[image: Вывод в терминале]

Comment: `append(a)` --> `append(a.copy())`

Comment: Спасибо большое

Comment: Дайте вопросу нормальный заголовок и перенесите сам текст в тело вопроса.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Во всем виновата ссылочная модель данных в `Python`.
Нужно делать так:

```
lst.append(lst.copy())
```